# Ratio test series convergence/divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[Click here for the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/envyU.jpg)

[image]

Please just give me a hint on how to start this problem before actually solving it, and if I can't figure it out on my own after that I will ask for further help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the most direct, simple way is with *the complete* ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

and now:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\begin{cases}\cfrac{8^2}{2^{-8}}\\{}\\\cfrac{2^{-8}}{8^2}\end{cases}$$

depending on the case...

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

we have

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} b_{2n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n}}=8^{-2}<1$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} b_{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_{2n+2}}{a_{2n+1}}=8^2>1.$$

so, the sequence $(b_n)$ ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the sequences $b_n=a_{2n}$ and $c_n=a_{2n+1}$. Also, consider $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ when $n$ is even and $n$ is odd.